# R error in xyplot Error in units == units[1L] : comparison of these types is not implemented

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a problem in R with the xyplot (lattice package). For some reason I get the following error:

> error in xyplot Error in units == units[1L]  comparison of these types
>   is not implemented.

this is the code I use:

```
xyplot(observed + predict ~ day | id, m, type="b", auto.key=TRUE, grid = TRUE)
```

the day column is the problem. if I replace it with any other variable from my dataframe it works. If I use a normal plot: `plot(mood ~ day, m)`  the plot gets created with no error.

Any ideas what the problem could be? If need I can provide some additional help.

Comment: It seems that it tries to compare a grid::unit object. Looks very much like a bug, try to look where it happens. Also what type of variable is day? Have you tried the most simple alternative: xyplot(predict ~ day, m, ...)?

Comment: Yeah I tried the simple alternative of the xyplot, but it throws the same error. day is a variable of type double that ranges from 1 to 56. The research is a repeated measures design with each row representing 1 day of the trial of 1 participant. (total of 30 participants). Is there maybe another plot function that can pull off what i am trying to do? (compare observed and predicted mood for each day in seperate plots per participant

Comment: 1- As far as I know `xyplot` is from `lattice` package, which is not mentioned here for some reason. 2- `ggplot` (which is mentioned) has thing to do here. 3- This is not reproducible. 4- It seems like it is mainly syntax and function definition issue here so this is OT and should be migrated to SO

Comment: Sorry for posting my question wrongly. However I wanted to let you all know, that i stumbled upon a solution. It seems the problem is with the scales. When adding scales = "free" into it, it worked (xyplot(observed + predict ~ day | id, m, type="b",  scales = "free", auto.key=TRUE, grid = TRUE)

Comment: Alice, if you have even a partial solution to your question, you should post it as an answer (and accept it if it actually solves your problem).

Comment: @AliceD: Try to run the code with day as an integer - if it represents days there is little benefit with a double